# How to style two elements in a row in MUI Select

Tags: css, material-ui

I am working on MUI Select v4.I need to arrange the elements in the order of 2 columns and not as a single column in dropdown.

[image: Image of output required]

I tried overriding some styles in MUI but didn't work. Any help is appreciated.
Attaching the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/oc1ox?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these styles to `MenuItem`

```js
<MenuItem sx={{ display: "inline-flex", width: "50%" }}>
  <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
  <ListItemText primary={name} />
</MenuItem>
```

[image: Edit MultipleSelectCheckmarks Material Demo (forked)]